# Enumerable.Where with a collection as parameter instead of extension method

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Can someone please explain this line for me?

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = Enumerable.Where(names, n => n.Length >= 4);
```

I understand this:

```
string[] names = { "Billy", "Bob", "Steve" }
var linq = from name in names
where (name.Length >= 4)
select name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are literally identical, and will compile down to exactly the same thing.  The second will simply be converted into the first by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Since Linq methods are just extension methods (google those if you haven't read about it yet), this:

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(names, n => n.Length >= 4);
```

Is the same as this:

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = names
                                      .Where(name => name.Length >= 4);
```

Does it make more sense now?

If it still doesn't make sense, google "c# lambdas" and "c# delegates".

Comment: I'll look into that, it still doesn't make sense. I understand some of it, I think I just need to read more about IEnumerable and lambdas

Answer (score 2):

The first line is calling the `IEnumerable.Where` Extension method directly, rather than via the `names` instance. More commonly (and in lots of examples online) it looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = names.Where(n => n.Length >= 4);
```

In this form its clearer too - reading across the line of code we have

> Filtered names equals names that have a length greater then (or equal to) 4

Answer (score 1):

That would usually be written as an extension method:

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = names.Where(n => n.Length >= 4);
```

I think its meaning is clearer in this form. It's equivalent to your query syntax: it gives you an enumerable that lists the names that are 4 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand how they are the same, try changing some of the code:

```
string[] names = { "Billy", "Bob", "Steve" };

var filteredNames1 = from n in names
    where (n.Length >= 4)
    select n;

IEnumerable<string> filteredNames2 = System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(names, n => n.Length >= 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable.Where（。。。。），Enumerable.Any(....)  , Enumerable.Aggregate(....), Enumerable has many methods,
In the bracket, you can use the collection name, then the linq statements)..
or in the below statement, you don't need to include the collection name inside the bracket..
IEnumerable filteredNames = names.Where(n => n.Length >= 4);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).